# Source code repository for io.kubernetes:client-java-api

Tags: java, kubernetes

The `io.kubernetes:client-java-api` library is in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kubernetes/client-java-api/6.0.1), where there is a link for a GitHub repository: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java.

But that repository seems to only contain the `io.kubernetes:client-java` library. For instance, it doesn't contain source files like `V1DeploymentStatusBuilder.java`.

The source files can be downloaded as a tarball from the [Central Repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/kubernetes/client-java-api/6.0.1/).

But where is the repository for `client-java-api`? Isn't it publicly accessible?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

The kubernetes folder in that repo is the API, if you look at the artifact it builds

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/pom.xml#L4

Maybe the class you're looking for no longer exists on the master branch, or the `*Builder.java` classes are generated at compile time